# How to get CSS background color to work with relative position?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS applied by bootstrap-css:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #fff; 
    background-color: #337ab7; 
}
```

This is being used for an ordered list which is using relative positions (the bootstrap angularjs navigation tree). I then use a 40px margin right to ensure that the item stays within the left navigation tool bar (using angular material md-sidenav). The issue I'm having is that the background color does not get applied to the margin right. Is there some css that I can change to ensure that the background color is applied to the margin section too?

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle? Would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you're mistaking margin for padding.

Comment: Thanks! You are spot on! Switching it to padding-right solves this!

Comment: Note, I also needed to highlight the entire li element like so:

.nav-pills > li.active, .nav-pills > li.active, .nav-pills > li.active {
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #337ab7; 
}

Comment: @Sam use `padding-right` instead of `margin-right`.